# Kanbanpad API calls (jQuery AJAX)

Tags: ajax, api, jquery

I'm having an issue getting this jQuery.ajax call to work. When the script executes I get an error (textStatus = "error"), but no error message (errorThrown = "").

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://www.kanbanpad.com/api/v1/projects.json',
    username: 'user@example.wtf',
    password: 'myAPIkey',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus+': '+errorThrown);
    }
});
```

If I manually hit the API URL (above) and type in my login credentials, I do get the proper JSON response. So, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Is my code malformed?

If you need more information about the API, go to http://www.kanbanpad.com/api/v1

Comment: what does the jqXHR object have to say?

Comment: @DefyGravity I don't know what you're asking, can you be more specific?

Comment: in function error :function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorthrown){
alert(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));}    JSON is from www.json.org.  or just look at it in a js debugger ;)

Comment: The jqXHR object is `{"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}`

Comment: If I try `jsonp` dataType, I get `{"readyState":4,"status":200,"statusText":"parsererror"}` as the jqXHR object and `errorThrown` = `jQuery15108416848906781524_1299986108143 was not called` which is odd, since according to jQuery documentation `error: function(){` should never be called when dataType is `jsonp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the fix:

Change URL value to `http://username%40domain.com:apikey@www.kanbanpad.com/api/v1...`

For whatever reason, jQuery (1.5.1, also tried with 1.4.4) is not passing the `username` and `password` parameters to the web server correctly (*or not at all?*), so rather than use those parameters, it can authenticate by including the credentials in the URL string.

Answer (score 1):

That page is using [HTTP basic auth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) but you are simply posting a username/password in your request. You have to properly set up the auth tokens and pass them in a header. Here is a [simple tutorial on HTTP basic auth over AJAX](http://coderseye.com/2007/how-to-do-http-basic-auth-in-ajax.html)--notice there is a jQuery specific example for the AJAX part.

Comment: I'm not saying you are wrong or anything, I just want to clarify. Because api.jquery.com documentation says `If the server performs HTTP authentication before providing a response, the user name and password pair can be sent via the username and password options.` So that is why I did it that way. Am I confusing 2 different types of authentication?

Comment: I never notice those in the API before, and I mistakenly thought you were passing those as parameters (in the data option). I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

use secured protocol for URL: https://www.kanbanpad.com/api/v1/projects.json, not http

Comment: Could you please explain why? Is there some official documentation you can quote?